# How to set up a keyboard shortcut for increasing/decreasing font size in IntelliJ editors?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Because my mouse scroll wheel increases the font in big jumps I need a way how to use something like cmd and + or something to increase and - to decrease the font like 12,13,14 px fonts instead current 12, 16, 20 etc.

But there seems to be no such option in IDEA or WebStorm.

How to achieve this via keyboard shortcuts?

By the way, when using the touch pad on my MacBook the font changes are as they should by 1. However my MacBook is in a clamshell mode and I am using an external keyboard and mouse, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There are Editor actions called Increase / Decrease font size that you can assign shortcuts to:

1. Invoke Find action (Cmd+Shift+A), start typing "Increase" in the search field.
2. Select "Increase font size" in the results list and press Option+Enter to assign a shortcut.
3. In the appeared window enter the shortcut that you would like to use.

Repeat the same steps for Decrease font size.